# why my text not inside container & keep i make two editable text in a file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter. I am a bit confused here. Why my text is not inside container and is this the right method if I have multi editable text, so I put it in one file instead separate both of them since the variable name and email address would be a different things. This is my design that I want and this is my code.[image]

```
class EditNameEmail extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<EditNameEmail> createState() => _EditNameEmailState();
}

class _EditNameEmailState extends State<EditNameEmail> {
  bool _isEnable = false; //_isEnable is the boolean variable and set it false, so we have to make it true when user tap on text
  TextEditingController _controller =
  TextEditingController(text: 'Wong Yuk Hei');  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Name',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState (() {
                      _isEnable = true;
                    });
                  }),
            ],
          ),

          Row(
            children: <Widget> [
              Container(
                width: 350, height: 25,
                decoration: BoxDecoration( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), 
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black) ),
                child: TextField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  controller: _controller,
                  enabled: _isEnable,
                ),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),

          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Email',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState (() {
                      _isEnable = true;
                    });
                  }),
            ],
          ),

          Row(
            children: <Widget> [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: 350, height: 25,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), 
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black) ),
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 1,
                    controller: _controller,
                    enabled: _isEnable,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the same controller for both text fields You need to separate both fields with different text editing controllers.

try this

```
class EditNameEmail extends StatefulWidget {
      
        @override
        State<EditNameEmail> createState() => _EditNameEmailState();
      }
      
      class _EditNameEmailState extends State<EditNameEmail> {
        bool _isEnableName = false; //_isEnable is the boolean variable and set it false, so we have to make it true when user tap on text
        bool _isEnableEmail = false; //_isEnable is the boolean variable and set it false, so we have to make it true when user tap on text
        TextEditingController _controllerName =
        TextEditingController(text: 'Wong Yuk Hei');
      
        TextEditingController _controllerEmail =
        TextEditingController(text: 'Wong Yuk Hei');
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Name',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(_isEnableName ? Icons.clear : Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState (() {
                            _isEnableName = !_isEnableName;
                          });
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
      
                Row(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    Container(
                      width: 350, height: 25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black) ),
                      child: TextField(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        controller: _controllerName,
                        enabled: _isEnableName,
                      ),
                    ),
      
                  ],
                ),
      
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Email',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(_isEnableEmail ? Icons.clear : Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState (() {
                            _isEnableEmail = !_isEnableEmail;
                          });
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
      
                Row(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 350, height: 25,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black) ),
                        child: TextField(
                          maxLines: 1,
                          controller: _controllerEmail,
                          enabled: _isEnableEmail,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
      
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: sir, how can I edit font size of controller name and controller email?

Comment: You can use style property of TextField to customize your input field. Like this

            TextField(
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 8,
                        color: Colors.blue.shade700,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),

Comment: if you find this solution please check this answer. Thanks! @rider2501